# Call a function that expects *args with unpacked **kwargs

Tags: python

Consider the following:

```
def foo(a, *args):
    pass


def bar(func, funcargs={}, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    func(**funcargs)
    ...
```

Where I can't call `foo` directly, but only pass it to `bar` with it's args. So I always create a `dict` of `funcargs` beforehand.

Now my current `foo()` has a signature of `foo(a, *args, **kwargs)`, and I need to pass it some `*args`. But I cannot create a `dict` of `*funcargs` and unpack a list of `*args` to it.

How can I solve this?

Comment: "So I always create a `dict` of `funcargs` beforehand." Why always a `dict`? Why does `bar` not also take a `tuple`? Why do you use `funcargs` for keyword arguments, instead of `funcargs: tuple` and `funckwargs: dict`?

Answer (score 0):

Pass an *explicit* sequence to `bar`.

```
def bar(func, funcargs, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    func(*funcargs)
    ...

bar(foo, [1,2,3], 9, a="b")
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to `args` and `kwargs` for `bar`, you must separately pass through positional and keyword arguments for `func` as well. To stay consistent with the naming scheme, take `func_args` as a `tuple` and `func_kwargs` as a `dict`:

```
def bar(func, func_args=(), func_kwargs={}, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    ...
```

This will unpack both positional and keyword arguments into `func`:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    print('foo got', args, kwargs)

bar(foo, (1, 2, 3, 4), {'five': 5, 'six': 6}, 7, 8, 9, ten=10, eleven=11)
# foo got (1, 2, 3, 4) {'five': 5, 'six': 6}
```